# Unable to configure XRay with Spring boot app

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-xray

I have a springboot app which is deployed as a docker image in AWS Lambda.
The app is working fine but i want to introduce X-Ray Traces in my app for debugging purpose.
I have tried to follow the official AWS doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-aop-spring.html. But of no help.

POM.XML:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public Filter TracingFilter(){
        return new AWSXRayServletFilter ("add-participant");
    }
}
```

**XRayInspector.java**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class XRayInspector extends AbstractXRayInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Map<String, Object>> generateMetadata(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Subsegment subsegment) {
        return super.generateMetadata(proceedingJoinPoint, subsegment);
    }

    @Override
    @Pointcut("@within(com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.XRayEnabled) && bean(*)")
    public void xrayEnabledClasses() {
        System.out.println ("I am inside the class");
    }
}
```

**ParticipantService.java**

```
@Service
@XRayEnabled
public class ParticipantService {
public void save (ParticipantRequest participantRequest) {
        Entity mySegment = AWSXRay.beginSegment("save-participant");
        AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder().setTraceEntity(mySegment);
        ParticipantCreatedEvent participantCreatedEvent = new ParticipantCreatedEvent
                (participantRequest.getEventId (), participantRequest.getTeamId (),
                        participantRequest.getFirstName (), participantRequest.getLastName (),
                        participantRequest.getEmail (), participantRequest.getContactNumber (),
                        participantRequest.getOrganization (), participantJpaRepository.findMaxDisplayOrder (participantRequest.getEventId ()) + 1);
        participant.setEventId (participantRequest.getEventId ());
        participant.save(createParticipantCommand, participantCreatedEvent);
        AWSXRay.endSegment();
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error:-

```
 Caused by: com.amazonaws.xray.exceptions.SubsegmentNotFoundException: Failed to end a subsegment: subsegment cannot be found.

at com.amazonaws.xray.contexts.LambdaSegmentContext.endSubsegment(LambdaSegmentContext.java:94) ~[aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core-1.2.1.jar!/:na]
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong !

Comment: I would log whatever your XRayInspector class is using as a subsegment because the error is self explanatory. After logging it I would try to understand why it is trying to use something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error means somewhere in the spring boot application a subsegment X-Ray SDK is trying to close is missing. You may follow the exception stack to find out and make sure there is always a subsegment created before closing it. Also, I noticed that you created a segment in your service. In Lambda, instrumenting X-Ray SDK is a little different compared to instrumenting application hosted on other services, that segment will always be created by Lambda runtime and the only trace context you need to create is subsegment.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-tracing.html